# What is the difference from macos tag here and the Apple SE community?

Tags: discussion

Formally macOS has a Unix certification, but in practice it might differ significantly from ordinary Unix derivatives. While questions about AppleScript like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327448/applescript-dialog-and-repeated-say-command-not-working-in-os-x-cronjob) have little interest for the general Linux/Unix community, Apple SE site reads:

> We do encourage AppleScript, Automator, and UNIX shell scripting questions as well as how to use tools like Xcode for non-language specific tasks.

The benefit of Unix SE is its narrowed scope:  if you read here an answer related to, say, Firefox or cURL, it will most likely apply to your system, while, if you find it on superuser.com, it can typically apply to Windows or macOS.

Insofar as macOS conforms to its Unix certification, ordinary Unix/Linux tags apply and there seems to be no need for the specific `macos` tag.

For cases when macOS chooses its very personal non-Unix path, e.g. Apple Script, should it be addressed to apple.SE or here (possibly creating duplicates)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Are you asking about what sort of macOS questions would be better here as opposed to [apple.se] or are you asking about how the _tag_ `macos` should be used on this site?

Comment: There are command line tools on macOS that are not present on other Unices, or that work differently from how they commonly work on e.g. Linux. As an example, `mktemp` [behaves slightly differently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555058/mktemp-on-macos-not-honouring-tmpdir) on macOS than what can be expected from experience on other Unices. As for questions about Apple Script etc. "front-end application" are explicitly not on topic here (see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The next issue is whether Apple Script could be considered "front-end".

Comment: @terdon: the first one, while, upon thinking, I find it difficult to find something that does not fall in the scope of Ask Different and so should be covered under the  `macOS` tag.

Comment: @Kusalananda: well, an Apple Script search gives 47 results, like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556357/44919)

Comment: I'm assuming that the [tag:macos] tag is just an example, as there are other tags that have the same relationship with other SE sites, e.g. [tag:vim], [tag:emacs], [tag:ubuntu], and [tag:latex].